# NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundExceotion in Appium automation

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, mobile, automation, appium-android

I created a maven project for appium automation using selenium in eclipse. In which I have a base class(Installing) and a child class(Menu) under src/test/java under one package. And page object class(Profile) which is in src/main/java in different folder. I have inherited (Installing with Menu) with the same project and I have also imported the other class(profile) to the child class(Menu).

I am using Testng framework in it(not Java application) to run the code. But I'm getting an error saying NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException. I have given the respective driver dependencies, selenium dependency, Java client dependency. I am unable to find the exact solution.

Below are the error:

**FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest automation_mobile_testing.APPIUM_PROJECT.Installing.Cap
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/Rotatable**

**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.Rotatable**

Using the below versions :
**Java - version 11
Appium - 2.0.1
TestNG version - 7.6.0**

I am doing this for appium automation. Can anyone help me out?

I have tried to update the project if there are any old versions. Even deleted the project and created a new project from scratch. Can I get an idea to resolve this?